# Ruby understanding multithreading

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to multithread loop in ruby following this exmaple: http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2010/05/very-simple-parallelization-with-ruby.html.

I copied that coded and wrote this:

```
module Enumerable

    def ignore_exception
        begin
            yield
        rescue Exception => e
            STDERR.puts e.message
        end
    end
    def in_parallel(n)
        t_queue = Queue.new
        threads = (1..n).map {
            Thread.new{ 
                while x = t_queue.deq
                    ignore_exception{ yield(x[0]) }
                end
            }
        }
        each{|x| t_queue << [x]}
        n.times{ t_queue << nil }
        threads.each{|t| 
            t.join 
            unless t[:out].nil?
                puts t[:out]
            end
        }
    end
end

ids.in_parallel(10){ |id|
 conn = open_conn(loc)
 out = conn.getData(id)
 Thread.current[:out] = out
}
```

The way I understand it is that it will dequeue 10 items at a time, process the block in the loop per id and join the 10 threads at the end, and repeat until finished. After running this code I get different results sometimes, especially if the size of my ids is less then 10, and I am confused why this is occuring.  Half the time it will not output anything for upto half the ids, even though I can check on server side that output for those ids exists. For example if the correct output is "Got id 1" and "Got id 2", it will only print out {"Got id 1"} or {"Got id 2"} or {"Got id 1", "Got id 2"}. My question is that is that is my understanding of this code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my code was the `open_conn()` function call, which was not thread safe. I fixed the issue by synchronizing around getting the connection handle:

```
connLock = Mutex.new
ids.in_parallel(10){ |id|
 conn = nil
 connLock.synchronize {
    conn = open_conn(loc)
 }
 out = conn.getData(id)
 Thread.current[:out] = out
}
```

Also should use http://peach.rubyforge.org/  for the loop parallelization by using:

```
 ids.peach(10){ |id| ... }
```